# How to re-use materials of a pasted object from another file for other objects in the scene?

Tags: materials, objects, shaders, workflow

I have copy pasted an object from one Blender file to another file. I wanted to link the materials of the pasted object to the other objects, since they'll have the same material nodes.

A) I'm doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to link the materials but nothing happens.

B) I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> apply all transformations to the copy/pasted object just in case it resets the objects data, but that ruins the node settings, the emission is suddenly lost and goes flat.

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: You can type `<kbd>Key</kbd>` to insert any shortcut into your posts and again, please always try to make your question title specific. Thanks

Comment: Can you select each object that you want to have this material and just choose material.002 from the materials dropdown list? I'm not sure what your intention is when you say "linked". All objects that you choose that material for will be sharing the same material so, in that sense they're linked. Modify the material on any of the objects and you modify it for them all.

Comment: Ok, one thing I noticed is that the 30 objects which I'm trying to apply the same material, I have already applied 2 different materials on them, that's why when I try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (materials) they are not changing. I  added a new object in my scene with no material and tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (materials) and the object changed.